# How do I parse a string to an object's name?

Tags: java, string, parsing, variables

So I have a small amount of objects (10 JLabels) and I want to change their text depending on the users input.

The Initializer for the labels goes like this:

```
private JLabel j1 = new JLabel();
private JLabel j2 = new JLabel();
private JLabel j3 = new JLabel();
...etc
```

and continues on to 10.

How do I mass change the text of each JLabel without writing each variable name every time?

I had an idea like below, but I don't know how to access the variable by name from strings.

```
for(int x=1;x<=10;x++){
  String d = (String) x; //this isn't what d equals, it's example.
  String label = "j"+x;
  label.setText(d); //I know this won't work, but this is what I want to do
}
```

Is there any way this can be done without errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an excellent chance to use an array to store your `JLabel` objects:

```
private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[10];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    labels[i] = new JLabel();
}

/* ... */

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    labels[i].setText("Hello from label " + i);
}
```

Comment: And a [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if you don't know the number of labels in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you have created the `JLabel` as an array like `JLabel j[10] = new JLabel[10]`. Then you can use the for loop to create an instance for each index and then set the text as well.

```
for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
  j[x] = new JLabel();
  String d = String.valueOf(x); 
  String label = "j"+x;
  j[x].setText(d);
}
```